# Keep previous items state in list Vue JS

Tags: iframe, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, youtube-iframe-api

I'm creating a simple chat app. The real time logic is done with sockets. I have a list with my `Message`(`messages` variable) objects and the final list to render(`chatItems`). The last one contains messages and date labels.
Also the logic for  YouTube videos recognition added too. If a message contains the YouTube video link, the `iframe` with YouTube player will be rendered. And if I'll try to add a new message to the list, the playing videos will be stopped, because a component will be re-rendered.

This is the code of how I'm getting the final list to render.

```
private messages: Message[] = []

get chatItems(): ChatItem[] {
   return this.messages.flatMap((message: Message, index, array) => {
      if (index !== array.length - 1) {
         let previousMessage = array[index + 1]
         let isTheSameDay = TimeHelper.areTimestampsOfTheSameDay(message.sentAt, previousMessage.sentAt)

         switch (isTheSameDay) {
            case true:
               return new ChatItem(message, 'message')
            case false: {
               let date = TimeHelper.getDateFromTimeStamp(message.sentAt)
               return [new ChatItem(message, 'message'), new ChatItem(date, 'date')]
            }
         }
      } else {
         let date = TimeHelper.getDateFromTimeStamp(message.sentAt)
         return [new ChatItem(message, 'message'), new ChatItem(date, 'date')]
      }
   })
}
```

And this is a `Message` component:

```
<div :class="$style.messageWrapper">
  <image :image="message.sentBy.user.photo" :is-avatar="true"/>
  <div :class="$style.messageContent">
    <div :class="$style.messageSenderSentAtWrapper">
      <span :class="$style.textMedium14px">{{ message.sentBy.user.name }}</span>
      <span :class="$style.textRegular12pxHelper">{{ formatSentTime(message.sentAt) }}</span>
    </div>

    <span :class="$style.messageBody" v=text="message.body"/>

    <div v-show="isYouTubeLink" :class="$style.messageYouTubePlayerWrapper">
      <iframe width="450" height="250"
              :srcdoc="youtubePlayerSrcDock"
              frameborder="0"
              allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
              allowfullscreen/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the question: how do I can prevent stopping of playing YouTube video in the `iframe` in my `Message` component? Accepting all the ways) Cause this is the big problem right now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the [:key](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)?